# What happens when nginx proxy_buffer_size is exceeded?

Tags: nginx, buffer

I am running a node server in AWS Elastic Beanstalk with Docker, which also uses nginx. One of my endpoints is responsible for image manipulation such as resizing etc. 
My logs show a lot of `ESOCKETTIMEDOUT` errors, which indicate it could be caused by an invalid url.

This is not the case as it is fairly basic to handle that scenario, and when I open the apparent invalid url, it loads an image just fine.

My research has so far led me to make the following changes:

1. Increase the timeout of the request module to 2000
2. Set the container uv_threadpool_size env variable to the max 128

While 1 has helped in improving response times somewhat, I don't see any improvements from 2. I have now come across the following warning in my server logs:

`an upstream response is buffered to a temporary file /var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp/0/12/1234567890 while reading upstream,`.

This makes me think that the `ESOCKETTIMEDOUT` errors could be due to the proxy_buffer_size being exceeded. But, I am not sure and I'd like some opinion on this before I continue making changes based on a hunch.

So I have 2 questions:

1. Would the nginx proxy_buffer_size result in an error if a) the size is exceeded in cases of manipulating a large image or b) the volume of requests maxes out the buffer size?
2. What are the cost impacts, if any, of updating the size. AWS memory, instance size etc?

I have come across [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/587386/an-upstream-response-is-buffered-to-a-temporary-file) helpful article but wanted some more opinion on if this would even help in my scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `proxy_buffer_size` is exceeded it creates a temporary file to use as a kind of "swap", which uses your storage, and if it is billable your cost will increase. When you increase `proxy_buffer_size` value you will use more RAM, which means you will have to pay for a larger one, or try your luck with the current one.

There is two things you should never make the user wait for processing: e-mails and images. It can lead to timeouts or even whole application unavailability. You can always use larger timeouts, or even more robust instances for those endpoints, but when it scales you WILL have problems.

I suggest you approach this differently: Make a image placeholder response and process those images asynchronously. When they are available as versioned resized images you can serve them normally. There is an [AWS article](https://aws.amazon.com/answers/web-applications/serverless-image-handler/) about something like this using lambda for it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, which is a good one. However, that doesn't really answer the question, which is what happens when the nginx proxy_buffer_size is exceeded and what the cost implications would be if it were increased.

Comment: I have added the stuff you are asking, sorry for that